# KeyError error using POIs service at openrouteservice.org

Tags: python, folium, openrouteservice

I get an error when using the openrouteservice.org POIs service.
The following code works fine, but when I change the coordinates, the 'KeyError:' osm_tags' error"  it happens.
My coordinates: coordinates = [34.798282, 48.514728]

In my coordinates ['name'] is not in English but in Persian. Could this be a problem?
How do I solve this problem?
Thankful

Code entitled "POIS - PLACES OF INTEREST" At the bottom of [this page](https://github.com/groundhogday321/python-openrouteservice-examples/blob/main/python%20openrouteservice.ipynb) .

Answer (score 0):

The answer I came up with is that for some places in my coordinates, 'osm_tags' does not exist. But there are for some places. For example, the code works correctly for the following locations:
guest_house: 106, hotel: 108, cinema: 299 .
The full list of these names is in the link below.

[link](https://github.com/GIScience/openpoiservice/blob/master/openpoiservice/server/categories/categories.yml)